# How to load Word Object Library properly in Visual Studio Express

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6

I'm trying to load the Word Object Library for Visual Basic in Visual Studio Express but having some trouble.

I go to the Project menu, Add Reference, COM and check Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library and click ok. But I still get the error "Word.application" is not defined etc. And when I type "word." there's no suggestion menu, it's not found.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: I sort of got it working with Dim AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") , but surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the top of your module add;

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```