# How do you manipulate a MS Word document (.docx) programmatically using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

I am trying to read from a .docx file (MS Word 2013) using vb.net and find and replace multiple words within the same document. I do not want to make use of a plugin or add-on within vb.net but rather program this myself.

Which libraries or references within vb.net will give me the ability manipulate MS Word documents with the .docx file extension.

Any related vb.net code for **Visual Studio 2013** would be greatly appreciated.

I have found the following  related information (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316383) although I am finding difficulty in adapting it for Visual Studio 2013.

Below is a list of COM references directly from Visual Studio 2013 and the only similar option with reference to the above link seems to be the checked item in the screen print below:

[image: Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library]

Comment: You should probably consume microsoft office Interop dlls related to ms word.

Comment: Here you go, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316383

Comment: Hello Tony, I found the same information that you have linked me to although the reference within Visual Studio 2013 is not available. Do you have any other suggestions for me?

Comment: Hey Matt, looking at Tony's suggestion it works fine within Visual Studio 2013, I would make sure you have word / office installed correctly, maybe a repair. The COM references come from Word itself not from VS or .NET.

Comment: Perhaps search google for c# controlling word via com example might be s good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that after a bit of "connecting the dots" from everyone's commentary (thank you) I was missing an imports reference that works with the "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library" associated with MS Word 2013.

With reference to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316383, the imports reference that I found was adapted from the question: [How to load Word Object Library properly in Visual Studio Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597396/how-to-load-word-object-library-properly-in-visual-studio-express) i.e. adding the following to the top of the object class solves this question:

`Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) to replace text in one or muliple documents, check the sample code here - [Replace text across many documents in Parallel](http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2010/12/replace-text-across-many-documents-in.html) . Hope I am not misunderstanding you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I did have a look at DocX however, I want to make a program that works like DocX.

Answer (score 0):

To run your application you need to have MS Word installed on the PC. I'd consider using the Open XML SDK instead. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for more information.